# Excel dictionary with multiple values?

Tags: arrays, excel, dictionary

In Python I am used to having something like a defaultdict where I can just append many values to a given key. In Excel it seems like if I use the Dictionary object from the Scripting Runtime, I can only add one item per key.

Is there a way I can do something like this:

1. If the dictionary lacks a key, add List(first item) under dict[key]
2. If the dictionary has the key, append item to pre-existing list under dict[key]

I hope I am being clear enough. Maybe instead of a list I mean an array, not sure.

Attempt:

```
        Dim collect As New collection

        If Not dict.Exists(key) Then
            dict.Add key, collect
        End If

        collect = dict.Item(key)
        collect.Add (val)

        dict.Item(key) = collect
```

Comment: That sounds pretty straightforward. VBA has a Collection object -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb7y698k(v=vs.90).aspx -- so you just write a pair of methods: One would take a dict, a key, and a value as parameters and reproduces the logic you pseudocoded in your question; use a Collection for the list of values. The other would take a dict and a key and return the values for the key in whatever form you like.

Comment: You need to add `Set` for your object assignments.  Then it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `Set` keyword required in VBA to assign to objects.  However you can get around them with a much more compact format anyway:

```
If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then dict.Add Key, New Collection

dict.Item(Key).Add Val
```

---

If you want to keep your old format, then this is how:

```
    Dim collect As New collection

    If Not dict.Exists(key) Then
        dict.Add key, collect
    End If

    Set collect = dict.Item(key)
    collect.Add (val)

    Set dict.Item(key) = collect
```

But the more compact format above works fine as well.

Comment: @user2680039 Sorry, should be fixed now.

Comment: @user2680039 OK, first example has been corrected for the "Argument not optional" problem.  The second problem is being caused by something else, probably the calling code or the code which preceeds this code.  You'll need to show us the whole routine and/or the code context of the caller.

Comment: This is very helpful !